# QGC: QML - How to draw a text label on a polygon (attach a label to a polygon\circle)

Tags: qt, qml, mapping

I'm new to QT, trying to add some features to QGroundControl.
I want to write a label on a polygon that is drawn on a map (like a GeoFence).
I tried adding a child label to the MapPolygon with no success.
The label should move with the polygon (if moved).
Can you give me any directions on how to proceed?
This is what I'm trying to achieve:
[Area is the label on top of the polygon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gd9Zt.png)

EDIT:
I'm trying to add the following items in one of the QMLs - QGCMapPolygonVisuals.qml (this will need more work in the background but I'm already stuck here):

Component {
id: polygonComponent

```
    MapPolygon {
        color:          mapPolygon.showAltColor ? altColor :interiorColor
        opacity:        interiorOpacity
        border.color:   borderColor
        border.width:   borderWidth
        path:           mapPolygon.path

        QGCLabel {
            text:               qsTr("Area 1")
            Layout.column:      0
            Layout.alignment:   Qt.AlignHCenter
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following errors:
qrc:/qml/QGroundControl/Controls/QGCMapPolygonVisuals.qml:282:9: QML MapPolygon: Geographic map items do not support child items
qrc:/qml/QGroundControl/Controls/QGCMapPolygonVisuals.qml:289:13: QML QGCLabel: deleting this child

Edit 2:

I succeeded (partly) by doing the following:

```
    Component {
    id: polygonComponent

    MapPolygon {
        color:          mapPolygon.showAltColor ? altColor : interiorColor
        opacity:        interiorOpacity
        border.color:   borderColor
        border.width:   borderWidth
        path:           mapPolygon.path

        QGCButton {
            _horizontalPadding: 0
            text:               qsTr("Area1")
            visible:            !mapPolygon.traceMode
            anchors.centerIn:   parent
        }
    }
}
```

This needs to get better but it's enough for now.
Thanks for the helpers.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You can use [MapItemGroup](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-mapitemgroup.html) to combine your polygon with maybe [MapQuickItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-mapquickitem.html) that can contain a QML arbitrary item like Text. But as Nir already said we need some code to provide a more appropriate answer.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I edited the question, trying to answer you @ניר

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with QGC if `MapPolygon` does not support childs and you want to put something on it you can do something like this:

```
Item{
   MapPolygon{
      id: mapPoly;
      ...
   }
   QGCLabel{
      ...
      x: mapPoly.x + mapPolt.width / 2;
      y: mapPoly.y + mapPoly.height / 2;
   }

}
```

Comment: When I try what you've suggested, I get the following error:  
TypeError: Property 'createObject' of object QDeclarativePolygonMapItem(0x1f534f8c570) is not a function

Comment: Thats weird.. does `QDeclarativePolygonMapItem`  extends `QItem`?

Comment: Can't find it in the project.
I added a button that doesn't do anything instead.
Thanks